# react-native weekly repeated local push notification

Tags: android, ios, react-native, alarm, react-native-push-notification

i've tried to make alarm to repeat sepecific weekday by using react-native-local-push-notification. i used react-native-push-notification (https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#readme), but in IOS it's not possible to set repeatType except "day".
do you have any idea to make weekly repeated alarm(weekly repeated push-notification)

```
 PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
                    id: parseInt(endAlarm.id),
                    title: 'endAlarm',
                    message: endAlarm.message,
                    date: endAlarm.date,
                    channelId: endAlarm.channelId,
                    number: endAlarm.number,
                    //android
                    vibrate: true,
                    vibration: 300,
                    visibility: 'public',
                    importance: 'high',

                    //both
                    playSound: true,
                    actions: ['OK'],
                    repeatType: 'week',

                })
```